# React - heavy lifting when processing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some of the props that get passed in to my React component need to be processed before I call render().

I am pretty sure I should be doing this processing in a function that is called by both the constructor and componentWillReceiveProps.

I don't see any benefit to storing the processed data in state as the only thing that can change it is my processing function - and a render is already about to happen when this processing is done so I don't need a change to this state to trigger a new render.

However, I'm not sure if storing component data outside of props or state is an anti pattern.

**Where should I store the results of this processing? In state or in a local class property?**

Answer (score 2):

You can store the results of this processing as a local class property attached to `this`. This is not an Anti Pattern as it is in line with ES6 best practices, which React is built on.

See this blog post:

"`this.<something>`
One of the least utilized features when working with React is `this`. People often forget that React is just JavaScript with ES2015 syntax. Anything you can do in JavaScript, you can also do in React.
The use case for `this` is to store values for which a change should not trigger a re-render".
-https://medium.freecodecamp.com/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00#.4oaiugfs6

Comment: I don't really understand what you're referring to regarding "ES6 best practices". Either way, it'd be good to include the relevant portions of the content you've linked to in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like to try to keep my components as simple as possible. Like you said, the component itself has no need to keep track of the state, as the data will not change.

I'd suggest using a [container](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-containers.html) to handle transforming the data, and only pass the presentation-ready data to the component for rendering. It doesn't have to be stored anywhere: it simply won't render until the transformation is complete.